# Handling Bad Inbound ISO8601 DateTime Offset with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework, timezone

My mobile client is sending up inaccurate datetime offset information. For example:

`2019-05-03T17:55:12-0700`

The time is actually the correct UTC time however, the offset should read `-0000`.

I can not currently modify the client to correct the issue causing this. So I need to throw out the offset or change it to `-0000`.

In the above example, for this user who has their account timezone settings set to PST, it stores the date in `validated_data` as `datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 4, 0, 55, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

If client-based time and offset information were synced up, this conversion by DRF would be correct, as it is seven hours off or PST + the current DST. (west coast us is currently -7:00 UTC)

The problem is that by the time I reach my ModelSerializer class, the `validated_data` already contains what DRF believes is now the correct UTC time.

Where is the appropriate place to mutate this field on the POST body so that by the time DRF attempts to create the DateTime it will build the correct timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this was to modify the DateTime object before it was saved in the model field. So in the `create()` get the original ISO8601 string from the POST body using `self.context['request'].data['created']`. Then use `dateutil.parser` to parse the string into a DateTime, and replace the timezone with a `pytz.UTC`.

```
import dateutil.parser

Class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

...

    def create(self, validated_data):
         scan.created = dateutil.parser.parse(self.context['request'].data['created']).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

It is not a glorious fix, but will work until I can release an updated mobile client.